# Using an unspread fragment in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

What are the dangers of calling `useFragment` on a fragment that has not been spread in any query? If I have a fragment that is like

```
fragment myfragment_Object on Object {
   ... do stuff
}
```

can I call `useFragment(myfragment_Object, objectRef)` even if the fragment is not spread on the query where the object is retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would work because a fragment is just asking for characteristics of your object. If you don't connect the fragment to a larger query then your objectRef wouldn't be referencing something tangible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).